# How do I secure an USB device to a computer so it can't be stolen?

Tags: usb

At my workplace we have USB microphones attached to PCs in high traffic areas. We are looking for a lock to put on the USB port so that will hold the mic in place. This doesn't even need to be locked, just tamper-proof so that it would be a hassle to detach.

Has anyone seen a product that would work for this solution?

Comment: Duct tape, perhaps? XD

Comment: May I ask why the USB port needs to be out in the open and not concealed?

Comment: How about a post-it saying "I licked this"

Answer (score 18):

[image]

There are *internal* USB ports, get something like [an internal USB adapter](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/how_to_make_an_internal_usb_adapter) and remove it from the bracket or use an [internal USB expansion module](http://www.nzxt.com/new/products/case_accessories/iu01_usb_expansion). Either mount the USB adaptor internally, or permanently fix it to a USB extension cable (cable tied to the inside of the case), and route it through a suitable office. If a headset dies, you're just out a usb extension cable and the dead headset

Comment: +1 Many USB cards have an interal port This is one http://ca.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/USB-2/Card/Low-Profile-3-Port-PCI-USB-20-Card-2-1-internal-ports~PCI220USBLP  It hides teh USB drive away and many cases can be locked easily

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried superglue?

[image]

Heck, there are even ways to remove superglue: [How to Remove Super Glue](http://www.ehow.com/video_17787_remove-super-glue.html)

Comment: Glue mold to the USB connector, make it look so disgusting that no one would want to touch it let along steal it...

Answer (score 11):

How about the NZXT Bunker Secure USB 2.0 Drive Bay? $24.99

http://www.legitreviews.com/article/1537/3/

[image]

The above image doesn't look like this would do anything for you, but the below image reveals how this could be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Although I like the superglue answer I can just imagine the IT guys pain when he needs to replace a broken headset.

I'd suggest a couple different things.  One is an all in one type of case like Dell sells with the small form factor OptiPlex workstations.  You can plug the device into the back and then put on the cover which can be secured.

The other option is to get a small lockable box with holes in each end.  The holes would actually be slots so that when the lid is opened the wire can be pulled out (up).  Attach the box to the desk and run a USB extension cable from the workstation to the box.  Plug the headset into the extension cable and then close and lock the box.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Conducting Glue](http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/b70c/)

[image: picture of wire glue]

Comment: How would this work? Wouldn't it effectively cross the USB leads?

Comment: You would only glue the outer shell, which is connected to ground.

Answer (score -1):

I still think the best idea is to have a USB cable extension run into a small lock box, like a hand gun lock-box, and keep the USB drive inside that. Someone would have to grind a 5mm hole at the edge of door for the USB extention cable to fit through. Most hand-gun boxes can be mounted securely to a desk so that's why I'd look for one of those. I doubt any office supply company will have a solution. Encryption of the drive alone won't work because if it's stolen the criminal won't get the data, but neither will you unless you backup constantly. I guess both a lock-box and encryption would be ideal.

Comment: This was more or less suggested by @waterwizard11 in 2011.

Comment: The OP is asking about a USB microphone. Have the microphone inside a locked box pretty much ensures the microphone will not work as intended.